# Android Preference Fragment OnBackPressed Crash

Tags: android, fragment, preferencefragment

i have implemented a PreferenceFragment, which i use to handle user preference.

The problem is when i pressed the back button of the device the app crash. 
I use the same method i use to load my fragment but onBackPressed make the activity crash.

```
FragmentSettings settings = new FragmentSettings(); 
ft.replace(R.id.container, settings);
ft.addToBackStack("settings");
ft.commit();
```

Here is the crash log :

```
12-26 09:53:54.351: E/InputEventSender(565): Exception dispatching finished signal.
12-26 09:53:54.351: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565): android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment FragmentSettings{421d3d10 #1 id=0x7f0a0000} did not call through to super.onPause()
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.app.Fragment.performPause(Fragment.java:1861)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:935)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1167)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:717)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1502)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:495)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2318)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2295)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3197)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2529)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2181)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4670)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4637)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4202)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4256)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4336)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4233)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4393)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4202)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4256)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4233)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4202)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4256)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4369)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4529)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2215)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1863)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1854)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2192)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
12-26 09:53:54.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(565):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Then :

```
12-26 09:56:06.561: D/AndroidRuntime(565): Shutting down VM
12-26 09:56:06.561: W/dalvikvm(565): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4194dc08)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565): Process: com.soclip.views, PID: 565
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565): android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment FragmentSettings{421d3d10 #1 id=0x7f0a0000} did not call through to super.onPause()
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.Fragment.performPause(Fragment.java:1861)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:935)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1167)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:717)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1502)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:495)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2318)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2295)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3197)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2529)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2181)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4670)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4637)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4202)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4256)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4336)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4233)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4393)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4202)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4256)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4233)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4202)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4256)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4369)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4529)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2215)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1863)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1854)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2192)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
12-26 09:56:06.651: E/AndroidRuntime(565):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help ? Thanks.

Comment: That code is the code you use to show the Settings, right? What do you do onBackPressed? What do you want the app to do onBackPressed? If you added previous fragment to the back stack then you don't need to code anything in the onBackPressed. Only call super, or not implement it at all.

Comment: adding to @hmartinezd Where is the crash log?

Comment: I do nothing on the onBackPRessed because i do not how to implement it in the fragment, i use this term to say that i pressed the back button. 
I just want to go back on my stack like the app does for all the fragment i load which are not preference fragment...

Comment: Ok, it's crashing because you are overriding the onBackPressed method, and you are not calling super. First thing you need to do in your onBackPressed method is call this super.onBackPressed() or probably you just can delete the all method if you don't need it.

Comment: I never override onBackPressed, neither in my neither on my fragment. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the log error

```
did not call through to super.onPause()
```

indicates that one of your fragment(s) has the onPause method but forgot to called super.onPause();
Check your fragment's onPause does indeed call `super.onPause();`.  Something like this.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    // code run before super
    super.onPause(); // <-- the super
    // code run after super
}
```